# Magento 2 Can this be left blank or set to $0.00 until the field is populated by the data from the simple item?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

Magento 2 how do achieve the below functionality for **configurable products**?

[image: configurable product]

Comment: is this custom option or configurable product?

Comment: configurable product

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the price to 0 without intervention by the script. For this there are configurable products. Configurable products do not have a default price.